# VueJs / Life cycle and Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to generate a carousel with Siema, but I can't make it work when slides are generated with a v-for.

**I don't have any errors I just have the feeling the new Siema function is called before the v-for is finished**

I put the javascript code into the mounted() of my component.

How can I make it work using v-for and not using static divisions ?

### App.vue

```
 <template>
       <carousel :my-array="myArray"></carousel>
    </template>
```

### Carousel.vue (not working)

```
<template>
    <div class="siema">
        <div v-for="(element, index) in myArray">{{index}}</div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import Siema from 'siema';

export default{
    props: ['myArray'],

    mounted() {
        new Siema();
    }

}
</script>
```

### Carousel.vue (working)

```
 <template>
       <div class="siema">
        <div>Hi, I'm slide 1</div>
        <div>Hi, I'm slide 2</div>
        <div>Hi, I'm slide 3</div>
        <div>Hi, I'm slide 4</div>
      </div>
    </template>


    <script>
    import Siema from 'siema';

    export default{
        props: ['myArray'],

        mounted() {
            new Siema();
        }

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think `<carousel :array="myArray"></carousel>` should be `<carousel :myArray="array"></carousel>`.

Comment: I'm sorry it was just a typing mistake. When I say it does not work, I don't have any errors I just have the feeling the new Siema function it's called before the v-for is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using mounted() it is working with updated()

Answer (score 0):

In vue.js if props are in camelCase you have to [use kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case) in HTML, like following

```
<carousel :my-array="myArray"></carousel>. –
```

Comment: I'm sorry it was just a typing mistake. When I say it does not work, I don't have any errors I just have the feeling the new Siema function it's called before the v-for is finished.